# What is this trumpet attachment called?

Tags: instruments, brass, trumpet

Last night, I was watching a television special featuring American music. I noticed that a trumpet player in the band had something attached to her instrument. It appears that the valves of the trumpet are extended far below where they would normally end.

[image]

What is the name of this attachment and what is its function?

EDIT:
I was able to find a much clearer picture:
[image]

The black sleeve around her arm leads me to believe that it is merely an accessibility device.

Comment: I never heard of an attachment to the valves. The instrument looks like a plain-vanilla [Flugelhorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flugelhorn) with piston valves to me.

Comment: Who's the player? If you don't know, who's the band? (Might be able to find other images.)

Comment: It isn't a flugel.  Best theory seems to be that the girl's got something wrong with her hand or arm.  An extension, screwed in place of the bottom valve cap, seems an excellent way of arranging a prosthetic device.  You need two, to give torque.  Three would be unnecessary,

Comment: fascinating.  never thought it would be for accessibility (if she had one artificial limb) but it makes sense.  Doesn't seem like such an addition would make much difference to the timbre, perhaps adding some more robust lower tones as the resonant body has more volume.

Comment: The "resonant body" is predominantly the air column within the instrument's tubing.  It won't pass through these extensions to the valve casings.  I think we can safely rate the sonic effect at zero.

Comment: @LaurencePayne- yep.  If we think about how trumpet valves work, we realize that the only acoustic length the vertical tubes add is their diameter, not their length- they are just shunts between the different lengths of horizontal tubing.  It's obviously a handle, not an acoustic part of the instrument.

Comment: There are trumpet attachments available to improve ergonomics, and valve weight systems that extend downward, but none to this extreme. It's safe to surmise that she's recovering from a broken arm or other such injury, and being very careful to not strain herself. In fact, why don't you find the source of the photo and email her (or her conductor)?

Comment: @EverettSteed: that would make a fine answer. Her sleeve suggests she suffers some kind of injury. No need to be a broken arm, though, it could be strain from holding a trumpet several hours a day every day.

Answer (score 1):

From the description it sounds as if it is a fluid cup on the bottom of the valves.  It would be there to prevent oil and saliva that would normally come out the bottom of the valves from dropping onto the floor.  Purpose is for sanitary reasons.

Comment: Note that the liquid that you remove from brass instruments with the water key is more water from the player's breath that condensed in contact with the tubing, rather than saliva. Sure, there's saliva in the mix as well, but it's mostly water. Or so I wish to believe ;)

Comment: Further, there's no such liquid (salive/water) coming from the bottom of the valves. It'd be oil. And given the volume of the thing shown in the picture, that'd be a LOT of oil.